# Regex throws false error at specific input

Tags: regex, email

I'd like to validate an email address input using the following regex:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

However, it doesn't match an email in this format `test@test.test-test.fr` while it should be matched.

Could someone can get me a hint, where the problem is?

Comment: Which regex group specifically is supposed to match `.test-test`, do you think? And, does it really match?

Comment: This question is a duplicate. See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1497596).

Comment: Also see: [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

The problem was the dash in the second part of the domain, it didn't matched the original pattern.